# how to load content while scrolling the page using bootstrap?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am going to use bootstrap in my project. Is it possible to load the contents when the user scrolls down the page like facebook? Is there any feature present in bootstrap or do we have to customize it.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are looking for something like Waypoints to create the infinite scroll:

http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/

Waypoints is a fantastic plugin, and it even has a built in shortcut for infinite scroll.

Answer (score 1):

It is call **infinite scroll** and this is not a feature of Bootstrap. You need a jQuery plugin by example.